# Get value from database and show in jqgrid table using xml?

Tags: jqgrid

this grid function..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#gridTable").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Grid/CallingFunction',
                    datatype: 'xml',
                    colNames: ['Name', 'Empno', 'Age', 'Address', 'Contactno', 'Salary'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: 'name', width: 200},
                        {name: 'empno', width: 100},
                        {name: 'age', width: 100},
                        {name: 'address', width: 100},
                        {name: 'contactno', width: 100},
                        {name: 'salary', width: 100}
                    ],
                    rowNum: 20,
                    height: 400,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 15],
                    pager: '#gridPager',
                    multiselect: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "Employee Details"
                }).navGrid("#gridPager", {edit: false, add: false, del: 'deletetext;', refreshtext: 'Refresh&nbsp;', searchtext: 'Find&nbsp;'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="gridTable" ></table>
        <div id="gridPager"></div>
    </body>
```

//this is connection class
public class ConnectionClass {

```
private String name, empno, address, contactno;

private int age, salary;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getEmpno() {
    return empno;
}

public void setEmpno(String empno) {
    this.empno = empno;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getContactno() {
    return contactno;
}

public void setContactno(String contactno) {
    this.contactno = contactno;
}

public String Database() {
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb", "root", "root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String s = "select * from employeegrid";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(s);
        while (rs.next()) {

            sb.append(rs.getString(1));
            sb.append(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)));
            sb.append(rs.getString(3));
            sb.append(rs.getString(4));
            sb.append(rs.getString(5));
            sb.append(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(6)));

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

//this is calling funtcion

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            ConnectionClass connectionclass = new ConnectionClass();
            String xml = connectionclass.Database();
            response.getWriter().write(xml);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A couple of things here. You need to format the code using the code format in the editor ({} button). Also, it helps if you describe what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: how to database value show in jqgrid using ajax..using xml or json